# How to add circular dependencies with node zod.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, zod

I am new to zod and have a circular dependency defined like this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod

```
const eDBAndSchema = z.object({
  and: z.array(z.lazy(() => eDBWhereSchema))
})

const eDBOrSchema = z.object({
  or: z.array(z.lazy(() => eDBWhereSchema))
})

const eDBWhereSchema = z.union([
  eDBAndSchema,
  eDBOrSchema,
  eDBClauseSchema
])
```

But it complains because they end up having type `any`

But it works in regular typescript

```
interface EDB_And {
    and: EDB_Where[];
}

interface EDB_Or {
    or: EDB_Where[];
}

type EDB_Where = EDB_And | EDB_Or | EDB_Clause;
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types: "*because of a limitation of TypeScript, their type can't be statically inferred. Instead you'll need to define the type definition manually, and provide it to Zod as a "type hint"*"

Comment: that is super confusing to understand. Do you know how to convert my code to use inference?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says about recursive types and recursive schemas,

> because of a limitation of TypeScript, their type can't be statically inferred. Instead you'll need to define the type definition manually, and provide it to Zod as a "type hint"

So basically you still have to declare your regular typescript typescript types and then use them in the schema definition:

```
interface EDB_And {
    and: EDB_Where[];
}

interface EDB_Or {
    or: EDB_Where[];
}

type EDB_Where = EDB_And | EDB_Or;

const lazyeDBWhereSchema = z.lazy(() => eDBWhereSchema);

const eDBAndSchema = z.object({
  and: z.array(lazyeDBWhereSchema)
});

const eDBOrSchema = z.object({
  or: z.array(lazyeDBWhereSchema)
});

const eDBWhereSchema: z.ZodType<EDB_Where> = z.union([
  eDBAndSchema,
  eDBOrSchema,
])
```

<sup>([playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wF5wGZQiOAIgwgBNCBuAKCuADsYBTKbZAY0bgFEARAIQD6AQTqk4AbypxpKUQC5u-AQHUAFs0YBtALrUAvjXpMW7Tr0EB5KBKkzoC8yvVQtuqgaowAnmDNK1GnAAvIqCImIAPqECVjRsEHSo8AA2yBhejPwBLgDKbOogyMGYAHSp6QAUFQCUwQB8cJl82Yx5BcjVcQlJjfzhbYyFxRglEABGAFaMbDAVktLI8qXIUFDIXhXlGVnOrfmDHe6dVPGJ8E1WA0MhI+NTM3O29sur65tp2827V4d6x6c9JotH4KEYALTIABUfIwADyOFoNG4lACudGACQqmlsTX6+0KABocfxLvjkETtNUgA))</sup>

You can only `z.infer` the types that are not part of the circle - in your example, there were none, except for maybe `eDBClauseSchema`. Assuming it does not depend on `eDBWhereSchema`, you could however still use inference on it, to integrate its type into the circular structure:

```
const eDBClauseSchema = …;

type EDB_Where = EDB_And | EDB_Or | z.infer<typeof eDBClauseSchema>;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

const eDBWhereSchema: z.ZodType<EDB_Where> = z.union([
  eDBAndSchema,
  eDBOrSchema,
  eDBClauseSchema,
]);
```